# Laravel-5.1 inject the current logged in user to my controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

How can I inject the current logged in user model to my controller?

For example, in my controller I currently have:

```
public function update(SaveAccountRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);

    $user->first_name = $request->get('first_name');
    $user->last_name = $request->get('last_name');
    $user->email = $request->get('email');

    if($request->has('password')) {
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
    }

    $user->save();

    return redirect('/admin/account')->with('success', 'Your details have been saved.');
}
```

But instead of having this line:

```
$user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
```

It would be nice just to inject the `User` model into my controller which loads in the already logged in user, so that I could us this instead:

```
public function update(SaveAccountRequest $request, User $user)
{
    $user->first_name = $request->get('first_name');
    $user->last_name = $request->get('last_name');
    $user->email = $request->get('email');

    if($request->has('password')) {
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
    }

    $user->save();

    return redirect('/admin/account')->with('success', 'Your details have been saved.');
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried using the user id, for the second parameter that's probably far easier.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Request` object (and in turn, any form request classes) have access to the currently authenticated user:

```
public function update(SaveAccountRequest $request)
{
    $user = $request->user();

    $user->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
    $user->last_name = $request->input('last_name');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');

    if ($request->has('password')) {
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
    }

    $user->save();

    return redirect('/admin/account')->with('success', 'Your details have been saved.');
}
```

No need to inject any thing, use façades, or query the database.

Also, if your attributes are marked as fillable you could just mass-assign them, without having to assign each property on your `User` model individually:

```php
$user = $request->user()->fill($request->except('password'));

if ($request->has('password')) {
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
}

$user->save();
```

Answer (score 9):

In order to have current user injected, you'll need to implement a simple service provider. **Two simple steps are needed** to achieve that:

1. Implement the provider

   ```
   //app/Providers/CurrentUserServiceProvider.php
   <?php namespace App\Providers;

   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

   class CurrentUserServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
     public function register() 
     {
       $this->app->bind(User::class, function ($app) {
         return Auth::user();  
       });
     }
   }
   ```
2. Register your provider

   ```
   //config/app.php
   'providers' => [
     //here go existing providers
     'App\Providers\CurrentUserServiceProvider'
   ]
   ```

Comment: You can find more details here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class

Comment: In 5.4 you need `return \Auth::user();` Note the \ prepending Auth

Answer (score 9):

Since laravel 5.0, the class `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` can be used to inject the currently logged in user into the controller or class being resolved from the ioc container.

Comment: this is the correct answer to the original question.

Comment: @chugadie - do you mean like this?

public function myAction(Authenticable $user)

Answer (score -1):

L5 you can try Facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Comment: a) If you look you'll see he's already using the Facade.

b) the question asks for dependency injection, not an anti-pattern.